# CNAME in Route 53 not redirecting traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have create a CNAME in Route53 to point to [my Elastic Beanstalk Enviroment](http://avraammavridis-env.bwrh4iit7c.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/) to redirect traffic from my domain to Beanstalk

[image]

Although the enviroment is up and running when I try to access my domain I am not getting any response.

**What I am missing?**

Comment: Can you use a "A Record" instead of a CNAME? That should be simpler...Create a A Record as "Alias" and point your elastic beanstalk endpoint to the "Alias Target". It takes a few hours to propagate...

Comment: @TomMelo you mean with an IP? Or just the url as here?

Comment: just the url as you've already pointed. When you create a A record as Alias, the Route 53 will show your Elastic Beanstalk endpoint in a combobox, then you just need to select it. Keep in mind that will take a few hours to propagate.

Comment: @TomMelo thx a lot. I did that. I will wait some hours.

Comment: @TomMelo I think the problem was that the domain NS and the one in Elastic Beanstalk were different, but I am not sure how many hours it takes to propagate the changes (?)

Comment: I my cases the time to propagate was really random, one took 4 hours, another one 6 hours and most of them more than 8 hours. Did you get any result?